# How can I get access to all the available colornames in neovim?

Tags: colors, neovim, xterm

I want to get quick access to all colors available via color names (like `"Red"`) in nvim.

Vim (without n) sources all colors from it's rtp ("/usr/share/vim/vim90/colors/lists/default.vim") as soon as defining a colorscheme.
All colors are available then via `let v:colornames`.

What would be the nvim equivalent to vims `let v:colornames`?

But any way would do to get a list of the available color names. Optimally to use them in lua.

---

Edit:

Another way to state the question to serve the usecase:
Is there a better way to check if a colorname like "Red" is available before passing it as a highlight value in `nvim_set_hl`.

Currently I would do it like this:

```lua
local is_col, _ = pcall(vim.api.nvim_set_hl, 0, "Normal", { fg = "Red" })
if is_col then print(is_col) end -- <-- true

local is_col, _ = pcall(vim.api.nvim_set_hl, 0, "Normal", { fg = "Redish" })
print(is_col) -- <-- false
```

Comment: Check `:help ctermbg` or `guibg`, supported color names are listed there.

Comment: That's unfortunately not closer to a solution if one want's to derive and use the color names programmatically.